# How to deal with Upstart “terminated with status 1”?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, upstart

I have a very simple script on Ubuntu 14.04 upstart (/etc/init/myscript.conf)

```
description "Something"
author "me"

start on filesystem and started networking
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 5 60  # give up restart after 5 respawns in 60 seconds

setuid www-data
setgid www-data

script
 exec python /somedir/somename.py >> /anotherdir/anothername.log
end script
```

I have three script like this calling each a different python script. Two are working, one says "terminated with status 1" in dmesg (even is respawned 5 times and failing each time). I have checked for ownership of the file .py (all www-data), permissions for dir and file (774), checked that typing in my terminal "python ..." (like root, like www-data, like me) starts the file normally (so there's no actual error in the py script). How can i deal with this error?

Comment: did you find a way to debug this?

Comment: nope, unfortunately. I gave up ^^'''